# I have a react-native app, was working fine, but now get request:Unauthorized and can't get the token

Tags: reactjs, react-native, axios

I have a react-native app, was working fine, but now get request:Unauthorized and can't get the token

i expect to get the token inside the data

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.